# Prove that $GH=IJ$.

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

I am given this graph:[image]

And the problem is given as: Let us take commont exterior tangent lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ for two disjoint cirles on the plane. Suppose that $\ell_1$ touches $\omega_1$ at the point $G$, $\ell_2$ touches $\omega_2$ at the point $I$. Suppose that the segment $GI$ intersects $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ at the points $H$ and $J$, respectively. Prove that $GH$ = $IJ$.

I have no idea how the conclusion is derived. Any help please?

Comment: You're expected to share your own work on the problem. From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): "**Avoid "no clue" questions**.
Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts. Such questions will most of the time be rejected by the community, ..."

Answer (score 3):

Consider the points $A$ and $B$ marked on the figure.

[image]

Using the concept of "Power of Point" into the circumference on the left side, we have:

$$ IH \cdot IG = IA^2$$ (1)

Similarly, on the circumference on the right side

$$ GJ \cdot IG = GB^2$$ (2)

Note that $GB = AI$, then from (1) and (2), we have:

$$ GJ \cdot IG = IH \cdot IG $$

$$ GJ  = IH $$

$$ GH + HJ  = IJ + HJ $$

$$ GH   = IJ$$

qed.